# Реализация "смещающегося сайта"

Tags: jquery

Хочу сделать следующее:

Сайт будет разделен на три составляющие: фото, видео, новости

При загрузке сайта открываются чисто новости, а по бокам стрелки влево-вправо.

При клике на стрелку "вправо" сайт блок с новостями смещается влево, а на место этого блока  приезжает блок с видео... то же самое и для фото

Примет: usatoday.com

Как лучше всего реализовать это?)

Спасибо)

Comment: DIV'ы, AJAX-загрузка, jQuery для обработки всего этого, а в чем сложность?

Comment: Как мне сверстать подобный шаблон?

создать все три блока для новостей, фото, видео, и скрывать ненужные? или как?

Comment: Возьмите за основу принцип реализации какого-нибудь слайд-шоу, как нарпимер, [вот это](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/01.html)

Comment: Ну... я бы сказал - загружать нужные, но для начала хотя бы так как вы написали.

Comment: на usatoday как-то стремно все реализовано, страницы грузятся каждый раз, после смещения loading...

Answer (score 1):

создайте div wrapper, в нем поместите ваши три блока, начальное left: минус ширина одного блока. при клике по стрелочкам меняйте значение left у wrapper`a